# How to add a break line after string input using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, line-breaks

I am setting up an Ecwid shop in my website.

There is this "SKU" string input field in which we are supposed to declare a name for our "SKU" string. We simply input our string in the input field.

Instead of using 1 word for the SKU, I want it to be 2 phrases, so my SKU string would be like this:

> yellow and blue, red and black

However, I want the SKU to be shown in the website with a line break. So it would be like this in the website:

> yellow and blue,
>
> red and black

It seems we cannot input code in the input field, it looks just like plain text. Maybe I'm not trying the corret code for the break line, but it seems that I must do something else to achieve this.

However, we do have the ability to create custom CSS for the SKU. But I do not know how to use the CSS to add a break line to the SKU string.

The default codes for the SKU are the following:

> /* Product sku */
>
> div.ecwid-productBrowser-sku {
>
> font: normal 13px tahoma, geneva, verdana, sans-serif;
>
> color: #1e2c38;
>
> word-wrap: break-word;
>
> }
>
> span.ecwid-productBrowser-sku-value {
>
> display:inline-block;
>
> }

Any ideas of customizing the CSS code or maybe inputing a code in the string field so the string has a break line?

Please do help, I've contacted Ecwid team but they are taking too long.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can try setting a specific width that is only wide enough for two words, but that isn't a very elegant solution (it wouldn't work if you had other lines of different lengths later on unless you gave this field a unique ID or class)

Comment: use a textarea instead of an input, and then set white-space:pre on the display tag

Comment: What does the html look like?

Comment: @dandavis
I've just checked the page code and the field is actually a TextBox, type "text". I tried the white-space:pre but it doesn't work

Comment: there's no such thing as a "TextBox" in html, which leads me to belive you're looking at a CMS menu of some sort. If that's the case, textarea might be filed under "multi-line text" or something like that... white-space will only work if you have a real line break, which cannot be entered on input[type=text]...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is not possible with just css. Unless you are able to wrap some sort of tag around one of the elements. Any tag would do (`<b>`, `<i>` etc..).

If you want to achieve the same thing with jQuery here's how you can do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sg5BB/35/

```
var test = $('.test').text();
var result = test.replace(/,/g,',<br/>');   

$('.test').html(result);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot! 
but I'm such a noob I don't know how to implement the jquery and put the corrected string where I want it to be

Comment: Then just put <br> after that string in markup manually. No other options you have in this case.